# The positional encoding in official transformer's release is different from the original paper

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformer-model

In the original paper *Attention is all you need*, the positional encoding is defined as:
[pe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr878.gif)

but in [Transformer's model_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/transformer/model/model_utils.py), I found that the formula is different at line 53. In the paper, the `sin` and `cos` functions appear alternately according to even or single dimension, while they are continuous in the half of the dimension respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but I don't think that makes any difference. The representation of each position with the positional encoding is unique no matter you concatenate `sin/cos` or make them alternately appear in the final vector.

As long as the encoding is unique and we always generate the encoding consistently, the positional information is preserved in the model.